# how to list all Domain Controllers in a forest based on domain name given using java?

Tags: active-directory

For a domain name given, need to list out all the Domain controllers that can be contacted. currently i am able to get only DCs for the domain i am connected right now. Some one can help me with this using JAVA?

Comment: What have you written so far? What parts work? Which do not work? Are there any errors?

Comment: No errors i discovered dcs for the domain my machine connected. but unable to discover dcs for other domain in the network.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the list of domain controllers for an Active Directory domain is a task that can be accomplished in several ways, of which the main ones are DNS and LDAP queries; if you are developing a Windows application, there also various API calls that can help you with that.

If you want to do this from Java, there are no native APIs you can use; thus you'll have to implement in Java one of the other available methods. A LDAP query would probably be the easiest solution.

---

### Update:

You said in your comment you want to find DCs for any domain, given the domain name; in this case, a LDAP query could not be feasible if you can't log in to the target domain (i.e. there is no trust relationship with it and you don't have a valid user account for that domain). This leaves only DNS queries as a valid solution, assuming of course you have DNS resolution in place for the target domain.